# Running Grunt with alternate config file location

Tags: node.js, foreman, gruntjs

Trying to run Grunt under foreman.  Ideally i'd like to house my gruntfile in ./build as opposed to '.'.

I've also tried doing it in foreman via "grunt: cd build && grunt watch".

Can't seem to get it to work.... Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

To hit a gruntfile in another location, you just need to use the `--gruntfile` flag.

For the directory structure you want:

`grunt --gruntfile ./build/grunt.js`

Comment: I believe this changed to be `--gruntfile` after 0.4